# How to enable scrolling with arrow keys?

Tags: firefox, keyboard

I have a problem on my enw Acer Aspire M3. When I'm using firefox and want to scroll a page down by pressing an arrowkey, instead of going down slowly, I get down instantly to bot button. How can I enable proper scrolling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. In settings under Advanced/General/Accessibility you have to uncheck "Always  use the cursor keys to navigate...". Then it is possible to simply use the cursor keys to navigate again. Seems irrational, but works.

Btw: The german translation says: Die Pfeiltasten benutzen, um Text markieren zu können, which means "beeing able to use the cursor keys to mark text", which is definately a totally wrong translation.